# Firestore v: 5.5.6 | Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have an error on firestore, my guess is that the tutorial i read has older version than mine. My question is, what would be the correct code in the version 5.5.6?

I highlighted the problem.

Comment: kindy check my issue as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058595/unable-to-fetch-data-from-cloudfirestore-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docChanges` is a **method** ([See here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docChanges)) .

so your code should be like:

`(querySnapshot.docChanges())[0].doc.data().userId ? true : false`

haven't tested yet, though it should work if the document is correct.
See also:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot